# Can we arrange all the vertices of a 2-connected graph so that sets A = {$v_1,..., v_k$} and B = {$v_{k+1}$, ..., $v_n$} induce connected subgraphs?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I think the answer to this is yes, and I was thinking about applying the fact that any two edges of a 2-connected graph lie on a common cycle, and then perhaps using Menger's Theorem on the vertex connectivity, but I am not sure how to put these two ideas together to find the subsets, and i'm even more lost on how to show all the subgraphs are connected. I'm not sure if this idea will even work. How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be our 2-connected graph.
Then $G$ is 2-edge-connected as well(!).
Take any minimal separating edge set $T$.
$G-T$ has exactly two components(!).
These two components determine the vertices for $A$ and $B$.

The parts with (!) may need additional proof if you do not know them.

Answer (score 0):

Take one vertex $n_1$ out of $G$. The remaining graph $G'$ is connected.

Then take another vertex $n_2$ that was originally connected to $n_1$ out of $G'$.

(1) If the remaining $G''$ is connected, then we are good.

(2) If the remaining $G''$ has $m$ components, we know all those components were originally connected with $n_2$.

(<1> and <2> are subcases of (2))
<1> If there exist one component with at least two verticeis out of the $m$ components, then we put $n_1$ and $n_2$ back to the remaining $m-1$ components and we are done.

<2> Otherwise after taking $n_1$ and $n_2$ out, all $m$ vertices are left as single points. Remember they are all connected to $n_2$.

([1] and [2] are subcases of <2>)
[1] If those $m$ vertices are all disconnected with $n_1$, then $n_2$ would violate the definition of 2-connection and hence not possible.

[2] If there exist $n_3$ connected with $n_1$ then taking $n_1$ and $n_3$ out (instead of $n_2$) would do the job.

Comment: I am confused how this would work for all k=1,...n. Can you explain that?

Comment: I thought your question meant "there exist two connected subgraph" but not "there exist two subgraph of size $k$ and $n-k$ given any $k$". Sorry for the misunderstanding.